# Max Date Function in Spotfire Visualization Title

Tags: spotfire

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to set a max date function into a title box of a visualization in Spotfire/McKesson Explorer.  I've tried referencing a Property Control using a couple commands but haven't had any luck.

Here are the two commands I've tried.
${MyProperty}
${My Data Table}.{MyProperty}

My end goal is to have each visualization state when it was last updated in the title, as they pull from different data sources.  The current property control is set up as so "Max([MyDateField])", and I set the property control as a string.

I also found this but I'm not sure if it's relevant...
http://spotfired.blogspot.com/2014/03/setting-property-and-set-it-to-max-date.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can, as you've figured out, use Document Properties in the title bar of any visualization with the syntax you've listed. however, `Max([Date])` is not a Document Property, and I can't think of a simple way to keep it updated. the linked post is one way but then it requires some interaction to trigger the IronPython script, so it's probably not ideal for an end user of your analysis.

your best bet is to instead use a Calculated Value in a Text Area visualization. using the expression `Max([Date])` will keep the value always current. you can make the whole Text Area bold and 12pt (or whatever your normal titlebar settings are), then shrink it to a reasonable size so that it appears to be a title bar for the visualization.

the only negative side effect is that if the analysis is viewed on another device that has a significant change in resolution, a vertical scroll bar may appear in the Text Area.

Comment: Thanks for the response niko.  I've gone with your approach for the meantime, and have learned a little bit more about coding since posting this.  I found this post somewhat helpful as well on the TIBCO forum.  https://tibbr.tibcommunity.com/tibbr/#!/users/48535/profile  Thanks so much!